# Ranges in Haskell (GHCi)

Tags: haskell

I'm reading [Learn You A Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/). [His examples](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#texas-ranges) `[2,2..20]` and `[3, 6..20]` work fine but I got three weird results:

1. Count by 17's from one to 171: `[17, 1..171]` yields the null list.
2. Count by 17's from seventeen to 1711111: `[17, 17..171111]` repeats the number `17` until I interrupt GHCi.
3. There is a weird difference between `take 54 [171, 234..]` and `take 54 [171, 244..]`:

   ```
    ghci> take 54 [171, 234..]
   [171,234,297,360,423,486,549,612,675,738,801,864,927,990,1053,1116,1179,1242,1305,1368,1431,1494,1557,1620,1683,1746,1809,1872,1935,1998,2061,2124,2187,2250,2313,2376,2439,2502,2565,2628,2691,2754,2817,2880,2943,3006,3069,3132,3195,3258,3321,3384,3447,3510]

    ghci> take 54 [171, 244..]
   [171,244,317,390,463,536,609,682,755,828,901,974,1047,1120,1193,1266,1339,1412,1485,1558,1631,1704,1777,1850,1923,1996,2069,2142,2215,2288,2361,2434,2507,2580,2653,2726,2799,2872,2945,3018,3091,3164,3237,3310,3383,3456,3529,3602,3675,3748,3821,3894,3967,4040]
   ```

Why?

Answer (score 74):

You have the meaning of ranges slightly off.  The Haskell range syntax is one of four things: `[first..]`, `[first,second..]`, `[first..last]`, `[first,second..last]`.  The examples from [*Learn You A Haskell*](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#texas-ranges) are

```
ghci> [2,4..20]  
[2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]  
ghci> [3,6..20]  
[3,6,9,12,15,18]
```

Note that in the first case, the list counts by twos, and in the second case, the list counts by threes.  That's because the *difference* between the first and second items is two and three, respectively.  In your syntax, you're trying to write `[first,step..last]` to get the list `[first,first+step,first+2*step,...,last]`; however, the step size of a range like that is actually the difference between the first two numbers.  Without a second element, the step size is always one; and without a final element, the list goes on forever (or until the maximum/minimum element of the type is reached).

Thus, let's look at your three examples:

- `[17,1..171] == []`.  Since you specify `17,1`, Haskell sees that the first two elements of your list ought to be seventeen and one, so you must be counting by `-16`.  In that case, Haskell wants to stop as soon as the elements are *smaller* than the last element---but they start that way, and so no elements are produced.  To count up by one, you want `[17,18..171]` (the first two elements of your list are 17 and 18), or simply `[17..171]`.
- `[17, 17..171111] == repeat 17`.  This one's fun.  Since the first two elements of your list are both `17`, Haskell determines that you must be counting up by zero—and it will happily keep counting up until the result exceeds `171111`.  Of course, when counting by zero, this will never happen, and so you get an infinite list of seventeens.  To count up by seventeen, you want `[17,34..171111]`, or `[17,17+17..171111]` if you think that's clearer.
- `take 54 [171,234..]` *vs.* `take 54 [171,244..]`.  I'm not sure what behavior you were expecting here, but what they're each doing is the same as above: the first returns a list of fifty-four integers, starting at `171` and counting by `234 - 171 = 63`; the second returns a list of fifty-four integers, starting at `171` and counting by `244 - 171 = 73`.  Each list goes on infinitely far (or at least until `maxBound`, if the lists are of finite `Ints` and not arbitrarily-large `Integers`), and so you just request the first fifty-four elements.

For some of the more nitty-gritty details on what range syntax means (it's translated into functions in the `Enum` type class), including slightly surprising behavior on ranges of floating-point numbers, [hammar has a good answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290438/haskell-ranges-and-floats/7290493#7290493).

Comment: I think the OP expected that in `[a, b .. c]`, the value `a` is the step size in a range starting with `b`. (As you point out, the step size is actually `b - a`.)

Answer (score 13):

Well, the semantics of those operations are a little bit different than you expect. The construct `[a,b..c]` is actually just syntactical sugar for `enumFromThenTo a b c`, which behaves a little bit like this:

Calculate `d = b - a`. The output of `[a,b..c]` is `[a,a+d,a+d+d,a+d+d+d,...]`. This is repeated, till `a+n*d > c`, if `d` and `c - a` have different signs (In this case, the list would be infinite, so there is no output instead), or till `maxBound` or `minBound` is reached, then the output ends. (Of course, this is implemented differently, since we are using arbitrary instances of `Enum` here).

So `[1,3..10]` becomes `[1,3,5,7,9]` and since `17 - 17 = 0`, `[17, 17..171111]` yields `[17,17+0,17+0+0...]`. And by that slightly complicated rule, `[17, 1..171]` yields the empty list.

To your addition: `[x,y..]` is implemented using the function `enumFromThen x y`, that behaves just like `enumFromThenTo`, except that there is no boundary condition, so if your `Enum` is infinite, so will be the resulting list.

Answer (score 4):

I, too, was a bit surprised by this behavior, so I wrote a range function that feels more natural to me (and maybe to you as well):

```
range step start end = takeWhile (<=end) $ iterate (+step) start
```

Citing your examples:

> Count by 17's from one to 171

is done by `range 17 1 171`, producing `[1,18,35,52,69,86,103,120,137,154,171]`

> Count by 17's from seventeen to 1711111

is done by `range 17 17 1711111`, producing `[17,34,51,68,85, ...`

Answer (score 2):

I was also confused by this tutorial: The tutorial uses the word step, which isn't explained, and in my view isn't what I think of as a step. It then shows the example which can easily be misinterpreted. since `[2,4..20]` looks like it means with a step 2 starting at 4.

The clue is in the output though:

```
ghci> [2,4..20]  
[2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]
```

if you look carefully (which I didn't). It means start at 2, the next being 4, with implicit step thenceforth of (4 - 2), carry on to output numbers in steps of 2 up to at most 20.

```
"ghci>" [1,6..20]
[1,6,11,16]
```

Note 20 is not output as 16 + 5 is greater than 20