# Strange result of List generation in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, range, ghci

From [Ranges in Haskell (GHCi)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958181/ranges-in-haskell-ghci) it's pretty much clear why the `[2, 2..20]` generate infinity list.

The next value is the same, that why this code produces infinity list.

And looks like it doesn't care about limit because of `[2, 2..2]` generate also infinity list.

**Question:**

Why the following code `[2, 2..(-20)]` generate empty list instead?

Comment: Because it each time checks if that value has reached the threshold already. In case of `(-20)` it has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In short**: This is *intended* behavior.

The `[x, y..z]` expression is syntactical sugar for `enumFromThenTo x y z` with [**`enumFromThenTo :: a -> a -> a -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:enumFromThenTo).

For `Integer`s it is implemented like:

> ```
> instance  Enum Integer  where
>     # ...
>     enumFromThenTo x y lim = enumDeltaToInteger x (y-x) lim
> ```

So it will call `enumDeltaToInteger 2 0 (-20)`. The [`enumDeltaToInteger` is implemented with [src]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Enum.html#enumDeltaToInteger):

> ```
> enumDeltaToInteger :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> [Integer]
> enumDeltaToInteger x delta lim
>   | delta >= 0 = up_list x delta lim
>   | otherwise  = dn_list x delta lim
> ```

Soo it is considered to be an `up_list`, and the `up_list` will increase until it has reached a value larger than `lim`:

> ```
> up_list :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> [Integer]
> up_list x0 delta lim = go (x0 :: Integer)
>                     where
>                         go x | x > lim   = []
>                              | otherwise = x : go (x+delta)
> ```

This is how it has been described in the [Haskell'10 report on the `Enum` class](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch6.html#x13-1310006.3.4):

> The sequence **`enumFromThenTo e1 e2 e3` is the list `[e1,e1 + i,e1 + 2i,…e3]`**, where the increment, `i`, is `e2 − e1`. **If the increment is positive or zero, the list terminates when the next element would be greater than `e3`**; the **list is empty if `e1 > e3`**. If the increment is negative, the list terminates when the next element would be less than `e3`; the list is empty if `e1 < e3`.

So the document says that if the "step" is zero or more, and `e1 > e3`, then the result is the empty list.

It is indeed a "tricky" case however. I personally agree that using a special case for `0` as "step" would make sense (although I'm not per se saying this is more favorable than using the `up_list` implementation). It is however how things are defined.