# The math behind 1.0999999999999999 in Haskell

Tags: haskell, floating-point, functional-programming, floating-accuracy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Haskell ranges and floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290438/haskell-ranges-and-floats)

Why does the following output occur in haskel:

```
[0.1,0.3..1]
[0.1,0.3,0.5,0.7,0.8999999999999999,1.0999999999999999]
```

1. What is the math behind the `1.0999999999999999` (I am on a 64bit linux machine if its useful)?
2. Why doesnt it stop at `0.8999999999999999` when obviously `1.0999999999999999` is out of range?

Comment: As for 1), what you're seeing is just the inaccurate representation of the decimal number 1.1 as a floating point number

Comment: @NiklasB. Still it doesnt explain why the inaccuracy in the first place if 0.3-0.1 is a clear 0.2 which is a rational number easily written in a floating point number

Comment: Where I come from, 0.3-0.1 is a clear 0.2, and 0.9 + 0.2 == 1.1. Keep in mind that you are *not* using rationals here, you are using floating point, which cannot represent arbitrary rationals accurately. You are mistaken in believing that 0.1 can be represented accuratly in the binary system.

Comment: @NiklasB. it was a typo... however, floating point 0.3 - 0.1 is not a problem to compute accurately right?

Comment: no - even .1 cannot be represented exactly with a floating point number

Comment: @user5402 0.1 can be represented accurately.

Comment: @footy This is not a Haskell problem, it is a computer language problem in general. See http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/

Comment: @footy No, you cannot represent `0.1` exactly in binary, e.g. [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_numeral_system#Fractions_in_binary).

Comment: If `f1` is the closest floating point number to `m1/n` and `f2` is the closest floating point number to `m2/n`, it does NOT follow that `f1+f2` is the closest floating point number to `(m1+m2)/n`.  And no, no IEEE floating point numbers are exactly equal to 0.1 or 0.2.

Comment: @MarkThomas The relevancy to Haskell is why the return value includes `1.09999...` at all, when it looks like the user is requesting numbers only up to `1.0`.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point shows that 0.1 can be easily represented right? What am I missing?

Comment: @footy It can't show that, since it simply isn't true. Can you link to the precise bit of the IEEE standard (or the Wikipedia article about the standard) that you believe shows that `0.1` has an exact decimal representation?

Comment: @ChrisTaylor .. now I understand! Thanks. For 0.1 its a recursive representation of .00011 in binary. Hence its an irrational number in binary!

Comment: @footy No, all periodic fractions are rational in all bases. It's a _nonterminating_ binary fraction, though.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor: IEEE 754 defines both binary and decimal floating point. It is incorrect to assert that floating point cannot represent .1 exactly. If you are explaining to somebody that the particular binary floating point implementation they are using cannot represent .1 accurately, you need to explain that it is binary.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Why the overshoot?

`[0.1,0.3..1]` is short for `enumFromThenTo 0.1 0.3 1.0`

The Haskell report says

> For Float and Double, the semantics of the enumFrom family is given by the rules for Int above, except that the list terminates when the elements become *greater than e3 + i∕2* for positive increment i, or when they become less than e3 + i∕2 for negative i.

Here `e3` = 1.0 and your increment `i` = 0.2, so `e3 + i∕2` = 1.1. It's only supposed to stop when it goes bigger than that.

You asked it to stop at 1, but it can only stop at 0.9 or 1.1. There's a rounding error (floating types are inherently inaccurate) and 1.1 has ended up as 1.09999999999, so since this is not greater than 1.0 + i/2, it's allowed.

In fact, even if it were *equal* to 1.0+i/2 it's allowed, as you can check using the exact `[0.1,0.3..1]::[Rational]` (after importing `Data.Ratio`).

You can avoid the problem by calculating the upper limit you're aiming for, 0.9, and specifying that: `[0.1,0.3..0.9]`. You won't suffer from rounding error unless your increment is small and your numbers are large, i.e. you're working beyond the accuracy of Double for large numbers.

### Why the inaccuracy?

1.09 recurring is mathematically indistinguishable from 1.1, but here we have a finite number of 9s, and that's strictly less than 1.1.

Floating point numbers are stored as if they're in scientific notation, eg 4.563347x10^-7, but in binary, so like 01.1001110101x2^01101110.

This means your number can only be stored completely accurately as a Float if you can express it by summing powers of two, just as you can only write a number in decimal if you can express is by summing powers of 10.

0.2 in your example is 0.001100110011 in binary, with the 0011 repeating forever and 1.1 is 1.0001100110011 again with 0011 repeating forever.

Since only a finite part of those will be stored, when converted back to decimal to show you, they'll be a little out. Often the difference is so small it gets rounded away again, but sometimes you can see it, as here.

This inherent inaccuracy is why `enumFromThenTo` lets you go above the top number - it's stopping you from having too few because of rounding errors.

Comment: The Haskell standard is broken.  It used to be correct, but it was changed.

Comment: @augustss: Can you elaborate?

Comment: The difference between the real floating point value and the desired mathematical entity doesn't get rounded away; it's just often not displayed on rendering as decimals.

Comment: @DonalFellows That's exactly what I meant by "converted back to decimal to show you...so small it gets rounded away again" meaning that there's a second rounding error on conversion to decimal _for the purposes of show_. I didn't mean to mislead anyone in to thinking the underlying floating point got edited in any way - this is Haskell after all and we don't do destructive update when applying the show function!

Comment: Well, we all know that Float and Double are best handled with care (and not to assume too much about their instances). On the other hand I'm a bit miffed with the behavior of Rational which is after all exact and for which there is no good reason to overshoot in their Enum instance.

Comment: I agree. There's no reason to overshoot. Let me hit the character limit to say that even 1.09999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999 is stored exactly in Rational

Comment: This is years late, but just in case some time traveler visits here in the future: the "Why the inaccuracy?" section is not correct. There really is an inaccuracy here: the number showed to you, and the closest `Double` (or `Float`) to `1.1`, are not the same. You can verify this by entering `0.1 + 0.2 + 0.2 + 0.2 + 0.2 + 0.2 == 1.1` (the left hand side is the calculation that produces `1.0999999999999999`) in ghci, which will reply `False`. It is not *just* an infelicity in conversion to decimal. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/791604).

Answer (score 9):

### The simple answer

To understand this behaviour, you need to know that the expression `[a,b..c]` will be desugared into `enumFromThenTo a b c` where `enumFromThenTo` is a method of the `Enum` class.

The [Haskell standard](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch6.html#x13-1310006.3.4) says that

> For `Float` and `Double`, the semantics of the `enumFrom` family is given by the rules for `Int` above, except that the list terminates when the elements become greater than `e3 + i∕2` for positive increment `i`, or when they become less than `e3 + i∕2` for negative `i`.

Standards are standards, after all. But that's not very satisfactory.

### Going deeper

The `Double` instance of `Enum` is defined in the module [GHC.Float](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/3.0.3.2/doc/html/src/GHC-Float.html), so let's look there. We find:

```
instance Enum Double where
  enumFromThenTo = numericFromThenTo
```

That's not *incredibly* helpful, but a quick Google search reveals that `numericFromThenTo` is defined in [GHC.Real](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/GHC-Real.html), so let's go there:

```
numericEnumFromThenTo e1 e2 e3 = takeWhile pred (numericEnumFromThen e1 e2)
                                where
                                 mid = (e2 - e1) / 2
                                 pred | e2 >= e1  = (<= e3 + mid)
                                      | otherwise = (>= e3 + mid)
```

That's a bit better. If we assume a sensible definition of `numericEnumFromThen`, then calling

```
numericEnumFromThenTo 0.1 0.3 1.0
```

will result in

```
takeWhile pred [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 1.1, 1.3 ...]
```

Since `e2 > e1`, the definition of `pred` is

```
pred = (<= e3 + mid)
  where
    mid = (e2 - e1) / 2
```

Therefore we will take elements (call them `x`) from this list as long as they satisfy `x <= e3 + mid`. Let's ask GHCi what that value is:

```
>> let (e1, e2, e3) = (0.1, 0.3, 1.0)
>> let mid = (e2 - e1) / 2
>> e3 + mid
1.1
```

That's why you see `1.09999...` in the list of results.

The reason that you see `1.0999...` instead of `1.1` is because `1.1` is not representable exactly in binary.

### The reasoning

Why would the standard prescribe such bizarre behaviour? Well, consider what might happen if you only took numbers that satisfied `(<= e3)`. Because of floating point error or nonrepresentability, `e3` may never appear in the list of generated numbers at all, which could mean that innocuous expressions like

```
[0.0,0.02 .. 0.1]
```

would result in

```
[0.0, 0.02, 0.04, 0.06, 0.08]
```

which seems a little bizarre. Because of the correction in `numericFromThenTo`, we make sure that we get the expected result for this (presumably more common) use case.

Comment: just a sidenote: `[0.0,0.02..0.1]` ==> `[0.0,2.0e-2,4.0e-2,6.0e-2,7.999999999999999e-2,9.999999999999998e-2]` ; `[1.1,1.3..2.1]` ==> `[1.1,1.3,1.5,1.7,1.9,2.0999999999999996]` ; `[11.1,11.3..12.1]` ==> `[11.1,11.3,11.500000000000002,11.700000000000003,11.900000000000004,12.100000000000005]`.