# Haskell assigning value to a variable inside a comprehension

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension

I'm having some issues with the following exercise:

I'm supposed to write a function that thats 3 numbers, x y n, being x and y the bottom and upper bounds of a list comprehension (respectively) and n being the number of partitions that comprehension will have.

E.g:

```
λ> partition 10 20 4
[10.0, 12.5, 15.0, 17.5, 20.0]
```

What I have done is the following:

```
partition :: Double -> Double -> Double -> [Double]
partition x y n = [a+b | b = (y-x) / n ,  a -> [x,b..y]]
```

I don't understand why i can't define the value of the b variable inside the comprehension, since when i try to run it i get the following error message:

```
parse error on input `='
```

NOTE: This is supposed to be a beginners exercise and this should have a simple resolution

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to use the `let` keyword:

```
partition x y n = [a+b | let b = (y-x)/n ,  a <- [x,x+b..y]]
```

Then you can use `b` as desired:

```
λ partition 10 20 4
[12.5,15.0,17.5,20.0,22.5]
```

Comment: The results differ. [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290438/haskell-ranges-and-floats).

Comment: Oh i didn't know i could use let inside a comprehension, thank you.
But that way the list goes up to y+b ( 22.5) instead of going just to 20.0, how can i fix it?

Comment: @user3237465 I don't really think that's related. The bug here is using `a+b` instead of just `a`, not anything to do with Haskell's funny enumeration rules.

Comment: @Daniel Wagner, yep, I didn't look at the first number and the length of the list. Anyway, it's "not safe" to use enumerations for floats like this.

Answer (score 3):

What variables? Everything is immutable :)

What you want is a `let` expression:

```
partition x y n = [let b = (y-x)/n in a+b | a <- [x,b..y]]
```

Also note the direction of the arrow: it comes from the list expression to `a`, not the other way around.

It looks more natural to move the common sub-expression away from the comprehension:

```
partition x y n = let b = (y-x)/n in [a+b | a <- [x,b..y]]
```

Comment: Probably `x,b..y` -> `x,x+b..y`

Comment: @chi: this makes sense, though I just fixed the syntax, not the semantics.