# Why does map return an additional element when using ranges in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, range, division

I've just started learning Haskell and found a strange thing.

Let we have a list:

```
ghci> [0,2..5]
[0,2,4]
```

It has 3 elements. When I use `map` with this list I get 3 element as output, for example:

```
ghci> map (+ 1) [0,2..5]
[1,3,5]
ghci> map (* 2) [0,2..5]
[0,4,8]
ghci> map (`div` 2) [0,2..5]
[0,1,2]
```

But when I use fractional division I get 4 elements in output list:

```
ghci> map (/ 2) [0,2..5]
[0.0,1.0,2.0,3.0]
ghci> length (map (/ 2) [0,2..5])
4
```

Could you please explain why `map` may return more elements then it was?

Thank you!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7290438/2541573

Comment: Note that `length (map f xs) == length (map f' xs')` for every `length xs == length xs'`. This *must* be true independently on the implementation of `map` since it derives from its type. `map` isn't able to distinguish between different types and hence decided how many elements to return.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's due to the implementation of `Enum` for `Float` and `Double`:

```
> [0,2..5] :: [Float]
[0.0,2.0,4.0,6.0]
```

It's not `map` doing it, but `Float`.  Specifically, if you call `enumFromThenTo 0 2 5 :: [Float]`, you'll get the same list.  You'll see the same results for `Double`.

This is hinted at in [the haskell report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch9.html#verbatim-224), but the behavior is definitely non-obvious.  Essentially, it comes down to the implementation of `numericEnumFromThenTo` (we're getting into some Haskell internals here), which is used by the `Enum Float` instance:

```
numericEnumFromThenTo n n' m = takeWhile p (numericEnumFromThen n n')  
    where  
        p | n' >= n   = (<= m + (n' - n) / 2)  
          | otherwise = (>= m + (n' - n) / 2) 

numericEnumFromThen n m = iterate (+ (m - n)) n
```

So you have `numericEnumFromThen 0.0 2.0` generating the list `[0.0,2.0,4.0,6.0,8.0,...]`, then you do `takeWhile p` on that, which in this case is equivalent to the function `\x -> x <= 5.0 + (2.0 - 0.0) / 2`, or more simply `\x -> x <= 6.0`, which is why `6.0` is included in the output list of `[0.0,2.0..5.0]`.

I can't explain *why* it's implemented this way, that's pretty baffling to me too, but hopefully I've answered the *how* for its implementation.

Comment: The why is that it's important that `[0,0.1..1]` always have eleven elements, whereas it doesn't really matter how many elements `[0,2..5]` has since it's nonsense in the first place.

Comment: To elaborate on @ReidBarton, the implementation of floating point ranges is designed so that the length is insensitive to rounding errors in the common case when the difference between start and end point is *approximately* a whole number of steps. The cutoff is instead put at the unlikely "opposite" case where there's a half step excess.