# result list of map is one longer

Tags: haskell

in this Haskell example the result is sometimes one longer than the base list. Any clue for this?

```
Prelude> let x3 = [1,3..10]
Prelude> x3
[1,3,5,7,9]
Prelude> length x3
5
Prelude> length $ map (+1) x3
5
Prelude> length $ map (*3) x3
5
Prelude> length $ map (/2) x3
6
Prelude> length $ map (/1) x3
6
Prelude> length $ map (`div`1) x3
5
Prelude> map log x3
   [0.0,1.0986122886681098,1.6094379124341003
   ,1.9459101490553132,2.1972245773362196,2.3978952727983707]
Prelude> length it
6
```

Comment: This must be due to the desugaring of `..`-defined lists, and how it behaves oddly with floating point numbers. See [Haskell ranges and floats](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7290438/2751851).

Comment: `[1,3..10]` is a bad idea, especially using floating point numbers. Use `[1,3..9]` instead, or `[1,3..11]`. Number `10` falls exactly in the middle of the last "step" (from 9 to 11), so rounding will decide whether the closest approximation to 10 is 9 or 11.

Comment: @chi, in my opinion, that puts the blame in the wrong place. Fractional numbers (and *especially* floating point representations) have no business being in the `Enum` class. The sane way to get a list of floats like this is `map fromIntegral [1,3..whatever]`.

Comment: ok I got it, the wole list is type converted (as a range list, not per element)

Comment: great question! `Prelude> length (map log x3) - length x3` => 
`1`. Very funny looking. :) Compare with  
`Prelude> map (`asTypeOf` 1) x3` => 
`[1,3,5,7,9]` ; 
`Prelude> map (`asTypeOf` 1.0) x3` => 
`[1.0,3.0,5.0,7.0,9.0,11.0]`. **No**, the list is not "converted". It does not exist at all, until its use. What exists, is the definition: `enumFromThenTo 1 3 10`. It is taken to be polymorphic, i.e. can have elements of any type which is in Num class. So until type is known, list doesn't exist. So at each use site it is built anew, esp. if types are different (if same types, it might get cached).

Comment: ("can have elements of any type which is in Num class." all elements must be of the same type, of course).

Answer (score 4):

As @duplode suggested, it has to do with how `..` behaves with floating point vs. integers:

```
Prelude> let x3 = [1,3..10] :: [Double]
Prelude> length x3
6
Prelude> let x3 = [1,3..10] :: [Int]
Prelude> length x3
5
```

Update in response to the comment...

A definition like this in ghci:

```
let xs = [1,3..11]
```

is polymorphic. The `..` is a shortcut for the `enumFromThenTo` function:

```
let xs = enumFromThenTo 1 3 11
```

The result is polymorphic - the above expression has type:

```
ghci> :t xs
x3 :: (Enum t, Num t) => [t]
```

If you just print it out, Haskell chooses to type is as `[Integer]`, and you get:

```
[1,3,5,7,9]
```

Here the Integer version of `enumFromThenTo` is being used.

However, if you apply a floating point operation to the list, Haskell interprets it as `[Double]`, and then it becomes one element longer for the reasons explained above:

```
ghci> map (+ 0.0) x3
[1.0,3.0,5.0,7.0,9.0,11.0]  -- length 6 now!
```

So the `map` operation "changes" the length of the list only because it changes the interpretation of its type which changes which `enumFromThenTo` function is called to construct it.

Upshot: A list defined like `[1,3..11]` does not have known length until its type is determined.

Comment: sorry, but the problem ist not the original list, but the computed list from map

Comment: updated answer - hopefully this explains it more.