# Haskell numerical integration via Trapezoidal rule results in wrong sign

Tags: haskell, numerical-methods

I've written some code that's meant to integrate a function numerically using the trapezoidal rule. It works, but the answer it produces has a wrong sign. Why might that be?

The code is:

```
integration :: (Double -> Double) -> Double -> Double -> Double
integration f a b = h * (f a + f b + partial_sum)
    where 
        h = (b - a) / 1000 
        most_parts  = map f (points (1000-1) h) 
        partial_sum = sum most_parts

points  :: Double -> Double -> [Double]
points x1 x2 
    | x1 <= 0 = []
    | otherwise = (x1*x2) : points (x1-1) x2
```

[Trapezoidal rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule)

The code is probably inelegant, but I'm only a student of Haskell and would like to deal with the current problem first and coding style matters after that.

Comment: Clearing up the coding style problems will make it easier to see what's going on and to test pieces in isolation.

Comment: True. I should learn to write good code and test it. But that'd probably come later.

Comment: Why do you put `x1*x2` in the `points` list? That doesn't make sense to me. You could just use a range comprehension there, though float ranges are a bit... weird. See [this post of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290438/haskell-ranges-and-floats/7296160#7296160) (I used the very example of trapezoidal integration there, to demonstrate why the strange behaviour of floats makes some sense).

Comment: Hint: missing a factor of 2.  Let there be 3 points.  You should  have `(b-a)/4*(f_1+2f_2+f_3).  Compare with your solution.

Comment: @karakfa, that's true, but not really my fault: I used a Wikipedia article in another language, which gives a different formula. Also, I doubt that's what affects the signs.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: I'm just trying to make a list of points that a function'll later work with.

Comment: Actually, the formula I'm using gives results that are closer to actual values than the one from the english article.

Comment: you points seems off  - for example the first point will be `999 * (b-a) / 1000` which is about `(b-a)` and the last point will be just `0` but shouln't those be from `a` to `b`? (aka: you missed a `+ a` there) - assuming the rest is ok then you will integrate from `0` to `b-a` instead of from `a` to `b`this way!

Comment: The order of points doesn't affect anything, if I understand the whole process right; it's the sum of their values that matters, and it doesn't depend on the order of points.

Comment: I am not talking about the order - see my answer (which produces reasonable results for basic functions - so chances are good it's not totally wrong ;) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it indeed was the points plus you had some factors wrong (the *inner* points are multiplied by 2) - this is the fixed version of your code:

```
integration :: (Double -> Double) -> Double -> Double -> Double
integration f a b = h * (f a + f b + innerSum) / 2
    where 
        h = (b - a) / 1000 
        innerPts  = map ((2*) . f . (a+)) (points (1000-1) h) 
        innerSum = sum innerPts

points  :: Double -> Double -> [Double]
points i x 
    | i <= 0 = []
    | otherwise = (i*x) : points (i-1) x
```

which gives sensible approximations (to 1000 points):

```
λ> integration (const 2) 1 2
2.0
λ> integration id 1 2
1.5

λ> integration (\x -> x*x) 1 2
2.3333334999999975

λ> 7/3
2.3333333333333335
```

Comment: Your `points` looks the same. I think both are shady because they count with `Double`, but I don't think the order of the point list matters for this algorithm.

Comment: @dfeuer: He moved `(+a)` into `integration`.

Comment: yes ... it was easier (aka I was to lazy to add another argument to points)

Comment: it's really not about any order - the only thing I might have f***ed up is that maybe I choose the wrong end of the intervals here - I'm really sleepy and I would not do it this way (points) but this really should be close to the wiki article (it's not that difficult)

Comment: @Chiffa: Well, this is an overkill, but you could create random polynomials, integrate them, and check whether your `integration` differs too much from the correct result.

Comment: The major aim for me is to learn to write code that would create such polynomials for me and then test other code with it. But thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 5):

<sub>Note: This answer is written in literate Haskell. Save it with `.lhs` as extension and load it in GHCi to test the solution.</sub>

## Finding the culprit

First of all, let's take a look at `integration`. In its current form, it contains only summation of function values `f x`. Even though the factors aren't correct at the moment, the overall approach is fine: you evaluate `f` at the grid points. However, we can use the following function to verify that there's something wrong:

```
ghci> integration (\x -> if x >= 10 then 1 else (-1)) 10 15
-4.985
```

Wait a second. `x` isn't even negative in [10,15]. This suggests that you use the wrong grid points.

## Grid points revisited

Even though you've linked the article, let's have a look at an exemplary use of the trapezoidal rule ([public domain, original file by Oleg Alexandrov](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Composite_trapezoidal_rule_illustration.svg)):

[image: trapezoidal rule]

Although this doesn't use a uniform grid, let's suppose that the 6 grid points are equidistant with grid distance `h = (b - a) / 5`. What are the `x` coordinates of those points?

```
x_0 = a + 0 * h (== a)
x_1 = a + 1 * h
x_2 = a + 2 * h
x_3 = a + 3 * h
x_4 = a + 4 * h
x_5 = a + 5 * h (== b)
```

If we use set `a = 10` and `b = 15` (and therefore `h = 1`), we should end up with `[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]`. Let's check your `points`. In this case, you would use `points 5 1` and end up with `[5,4,3,2,1]`.

And there's the error. `points` doesn't respect the boundary. We can easily fix this by using `pointsWithOffset`:

```
> points  :: Double -> Double -> [Double]
> points x1 x2 
>     | x1 <= 0 = []
>     | otherwise = (x1*x2) : points (x1-1) x2
>
> pointsWithOffset :: Double -> Double -> Double -> [Double]
> pointsWithOffset x1 x2 offset = map (+offset) (points x1 x2)
```

That way, we can still use your current `points` definition to generate grid points from `x1` to `0` (almost). If we use `integration` with `pointsWithOffset`, we end up with

```
integration :: (Double -> Double) -> Double -> Double -> Double
integration f a b = h * (f a + f b + partial_sum)
    where 
        h = (b - a) / 1000 
        most_parts  = map f (pointsWithOffset (1000-1) h a)  
        partial_sum = sum most_parts
```

## Tying up loose ends

However, this doesn't take into account that you use all inner points twice in the trapezoid rule. If we add the factors, we end up with

```
> integration :: (Double -> Double) -> Double -> Double -> Double
> integration f a b = 
>      h / 2 * (f a + f b + 2 * partial_sum)
>    --    ^^^              ^^^
>    where 
>        h = (b - a) / 1000 
>        most_parts  = map f (pointsWithOffset (1000-1) h a)  
>        partial_sum = sum most_parts
```

Which yields the correct value for our test function above.

## Exercise

Your current version only supports `1000` grid points. Add an `Int` argument so that one can change the number of grid points:

```
integration :: Int -> (Double -> Double) -> Double -> Double -> Double
integration n f a b = -- ...
```

Furthermore, try to write `points` in different ways, for example go from `a` to `b`, use `takeWhile` and `iterate`, or even a list comprehension.

Comment: A good technique for avoiding weird fence-post issues when counting in floating point is `map (arbitraryTransformation . fromIntegral)`. Of course, this all changes if you use variable-width intervals.

Comment: That is a great answer. I regret being able to give it only 1 point. Also, should I look into literal Haskell. As a student, I  don't yet know what that is.

Comment: @Chiffa: You know how you usually use `--` or `{- ... -}` for comments? *Literate* programming basically flips everything around. Everything is interpreted as a comment, unless you use special syntax (in this case `> ...`, which is also called Bird style).

Comment: My function is a result of an exercise. Surely a real-life, well-designed function should have an argument for the number of points. As for `iterate`, I'm yet to learn about it.

Comment: @Chiffa: Remark: I use literate Haskell only on StackOverflow, so that one can copy and paste the whole answer into an editor/file. I usually don't use it for my own projects.