# Trapezoid Rule in Haskell

Tags: haskell, integration

I'm trying to define the trapezoid rule in Haskell. I created a helper function innerSum, which is sum portion of the trapezoid rule. Then in the integral definition I multiple by the distance and take in the lower bound, upper bound, a function, and some n number of trapezoids.As n increases the answer should become more accurate. My function seems to work for most cases

except this case (and likely others):
definiteIntegral (-1) 1 (\x->x^100) 20.

As I change the value for 20 instead of my answers diverging to a certain and getting more accurate, the numbers just jump randomly. I cannot seem to find the mistake

```
definiteIntegral :: Double -> Double -> (Double -> Double) -> Integer -> Double
definiteIntegral a b g n | a <= b = (dist a b n)*(innerSum a b g (dist a b n))
                         | otherwise = (dist a b n)*(innerSum b a g (dist b a n))
                         where dist a b n = (b-a)/(fromIntegral n::Double)

innerSum :: Double -> Double -> (Double -> Double) -> Double -> Double
innerSum a b g d | a >= b = 0
                 | otherwise = (((g a) + (g (a + d)))/2)+(innerSum (a + d) b g d)
```

Comment: I don't think this is a haskell specific problem but has to  do with numerical accuracy and rounding error due to floating point arithmetic.

Comment: It won't be entirely accurate because of this, yes, but it still not jump so drastically

Comment: Also note that if you increase the number of triangles `definiteIntegral (-1) 1 (^100) 100000` you get very close to the "right answer" 2/101=0.0198

Answer (score 5):

The problem is your end condition. You calculate the step size so *in principle*, you should end up exactly at the right boundary after `n` steps. And indeed that will work if you make sure the step size can be exactly represented in floating-point, i.e. a multiple of a power of two:

```
*Main> definiteIntegral (-1) 1 (^100) <$> [64, 128, 256, 512, 1024]
[3.396429282002939e-2,2.3718601030590182e-2,2.08093271780123e-2,2.0055667986086628e-2,1.9865519301509465e-2]
     -- convergence towards 1.98×10⁻²
```

But most numbers [can *not* be exactly represented in FP](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), therefore you'll regularly *not* hit the right boundary exactly. If the last point falls slightly short of that bound, the algorithm will do an entire extra step, i.e. you blow up a small float inaccuracy to an entire-step inaccuracy. Numerically speaking, it's “just” an order-1 error, because that single step size gets ever smaller as you increase the resolution. (It's still bad, because the trapezoidal rule should actually be second-order accurate!)

Problem with `(^100)` in particular is: that function is very close to zero on most of the interval [-1,1], but grows very quickly in the vicinity of ±1. Therefore the result of the interval is *dominated* by the trapezes right next to the boundary, and even more by a trapeze outside the boundary!

The easiest fix is to get rid of that `innerSum` function and use built-in tools instead:

```
definiteIntegral :: Double -> Double -> (Double -> Double) -> Integer -> Double
definiteIntegral a b g n
    | a <= b = - definiteIntegral b a g n
    | otherwise = δ * sum [ (g x + g (x+δ))/2
                          | x <- [a, a+δ .. b] ]
 where δ = (b-a) / fromIntegral n
```

It is explained [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290438/haskell-ranges-and-floats/7296160#7296160) why that works reliable even when the step size is not exactly represented: float ranges like `[a, a+δ .. b]` refuse to take an extra step if the previous one is already close to the boundary and the next one would take you far beyond the boundary.

Comment: Just for clarification FP is floating point here not functional programming?!

Comment: @epsilonhalbe no no, it's a little-known fact that the number 42 can only be expressed approximately in pure functional programming languages, because else the universe would collapse and be replaced by something even stranger...